# vue.js @emit is not picked up by parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, parent-child, emit, vue-options-api

In my app I have a form, in the `ManageCards` component, that conatins a child component `ImageUpload`, that emits and imagefile and its local URL to the parent:

```
<form  class="mb-3" > 
  <div class="form-group">
    <h4>{{card.description}}</h4>
    <textarea  class="form-control" :placeholder="card.description" v-model="card.description" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img  v-if="card.picture" class="img-circle" style="width:150px"  v-bind:src="card.picture" />
  </div>
  <div id="preview">
    <h4>Preview</h4>
    <ImageUpload  :imgUrl="url" @newPicture="updatePicture"></ImageUpload> 
    <button @click="addCard" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="color:white">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

De `addCard` method calls a POST command to send information to the API:

```
addCard() {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('title',this.card.title);
  formData.append('description',this.card.description);
  formData.append('imagefile',this.selectedFile);
  formData.append('game_id',this.currentGame.id);
  // ...
}
```

SelectedFile and card.picture should be populated by the emitted method updatePicture:

```
updatePicture(imageData) {
  console.log("emit ontvangen");
  this.selectedFile = imageData.file;
  this.card.picture = imageData.picture;
  // ...
}
```

The `ImageUpload` Component itself  looks like:

```
<template>
  <div class="Image-Upload-wrapper Image-upload"> 
    <div>
      <input type="file" v-on:change="onFileChange" ref="fileUpload" id="file_picture_input" />
      <label for="file_picture_input" class="upload_picture_button">Kies afbeelding</label>
    </div>
    <div id="croppie"></div>     
    <div class="upload-wrapper">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" v-on:click="setImage">
        <!-- type="button"" anders vervest de knop de hele pagina " -->
        Set image   
      </button>
    </div>   
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// uitleg over Croppie::https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kvNozA8M1HM
import Croppie from 'croppie';

export default {
  props: [
    'imgUrl'
  ],
  mounted() {
    this.setUpCroppie()
  },
  data() {
    return {
      croppie: null,
      croppieImage: '',
      selectedFile: '',
      picture: '',
      url: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setUpCroppie() {
      let el = document.getElementById('croppie');
      this.croppie = new Croppie(el, {
        viewport: { width: 200, height:200, type:'circle' },
        boundary: { width: 220, height:220 },
        showZoomer: true,
        enableOrientation: true
      });
      this.croppie.bind({       
        url: this.url
      });
    },
    setImage() {
      this.croppie.result({
        type: 'canvas',
        size: 'viewport'
      })
      .then(blob =>fetch(blob))
      .then(res => res.arrayBuffer)
      .then(buf => new File([buf], this.croppieImage.name, { type:'image/png' }))
      .then(file => { 
        this.croppieImage = file;
        this.picture = URL.createObjectURL(this.croppieImage);
        const imageData = {
          picture: this.picture, 
          file: this.croppieImage
        };
        console.log("klaar voor emit...?");
        this.$emit('newPicture', imageData);
        this.url = '';
      })
    },
    onFileChange(e) { 
      if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
        this.selectedFile = e.target.files[0];
        console.log("gekozen file is: " + this.selectedFile.name);
        this.url = URL.createObjectURL(this.selectedFile);
        this.croppie.bind({
          url: this.url
        });
      } else {
        // Geen afbeelding geselecteerd, instellen op een standaardwaarde (bijv. een lege string)
        this.selectedFile = null;
        this.url = '';
      }
    } 
  },
}
</script>
```

In the Console I do see: `klaar voor emit...?`, from the `setImage` method in the chold component.
I do not see the `emit ontvangen` from the emit method in the parent.
Consequently the required fields for the POST command are also not populated.

Can anyone see what (probably silly) mistake I am making?

Comment: Your code looks fine at first glance, its functionality cannot be tested without reproduction. If I had to guess, you might not be observing the emit in the right place.

Comment: From the [Croppie NPM description](https://www.npmjs.com/package/croppie), it is also apparent that there is an optimized version for Vue.js called [`vue-croppie`](https://github.com/jofftiquez/vue-croppie). 
I assume they might have addressed inter-component communication here, or Vue's native solutions might already provide the necessary information. It's not inconceivable that the error you encountered with the original Croppie package could have been caused by DOM updates.

Answer (score 1):

### Child Element

A child element needs to declare the emits.

###### Options API

```js
export default {
  emits: ['first-emit-name', 'second-emit-name'],
}
```

###### Composition API

```js
const emit = defineEmits(['first-emit-name', 'second-emit-name'])
```

After this, it will forward the declared emits to the parent element in Vue.

###### Options API

```js
this.$emit('first-emit-name')
this.$emit('second-emit-name')
```

###### Composition API

```js
// After const emit declaration
emit('first-emit-name')
emit('second-emit-name')
```

### Parent Element

```html
<ChildElement @first-emit-name="(e) => ..." @second-emit-name="(e) => ...">
```

Comment: this did not solve the problem.

Comment: The emit declaration is not mandatory I see in the documentation. Furthermore, the component works in another parent where I use it..

Comment: I don't know what could be going wrong; I followed the documentation for what I wrote, and I've never had any issues or problems with it. Is it possible that the function responsible for triggering the emit isn't running?

Comment: [Vue Playground](https://shorturl.at/bzFI7) - 
I've simplified your emit operation to the functions you believed were faulty. It's clear from the playground that there's nothing wrong with the emit. My response in this regard is correct. Your issue must be somewhere else in the code, for which you haven't provided reproduction, so I can't test it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Staring from a simplified version again seems to be a good idea. I will look into it after next week. I cannot share the whole code I think, that would become to elaborate for this platform I guess.